# Get iPhone Go Button to Submit Form

Tags: iphone, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a mailing list sign up form on my website, and the button that fires it has got `<input type="submit"` . However, when I visit my website on my iPhone, the go button does not do anything. How do I fix this? Here is my full code:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form action="//isaacadni.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0db50d6b1ce1ac34d3194a969&amp;id=0026019372" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email form-control input-lg" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
                    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_0db50d6b1ce1ac34d3194a969_0026019372" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" btnSubmitclass="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> 
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: This works on other devices (ie desktops) just not mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `target="_blank"` from the `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can force it by replacing your input line with this,

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" onclick="document.getElementById('mce-EMAIL').submit()" btnSubmitclass="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```